# Qt Creator kept warning about "Cannot create file ... : Permission denied"

Tags: 16.04, qt-creator

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, and did a fresh install of qt creator. Using this command:

```bsh
$ ./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.1.1-online.run
```

The Qt folder after installation is like:

```bsh
$ ll
total 127000
drwxrwxrwx  8 dx dx     4096 Jul 19 04:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 62 dx dx     4096 Jul 19 04:16 ../
drwxrwxr-x  7 dx dx     4096 Jul 19 04:04 5.12.4/
-rw-rw-rw-  1 dx dx    36667 Jul 19 04:05 components.xml
drwxrwxr-x  2 dx dx     4096 Jul 19 04:04 dist/
drwxrwxr-x  3 dx dx     4096 Jul 19 04:03 Docs/
drwxrwxr-x  3 dx dx     4096 Jul 19 04:03 Examples/
-rw-rw-rw-  1 dx dx  2184658 Jul 19 04:33 InstallationLog.txt
-rw-rw-rw-  1 dx dx       48 Jul 19 04:05 installer.dat
drwxr-xr-x  2 dx dx     4096 Jul 19 04:03 Licenses/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dx dx 32903547 Jul 19 04:05 MaintenanceTool*
-rw-rw-rw-  1 dx dx 94833364 Jul 19 04:05 MaintenanceTool.dat
-rw-rw-rw-  1 dx dx    18836 Jul 19 04:05 MaintenanceTool.ini
-rw-rw-rw-  1 dx dx      362 Jul 19 04:05 network.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 dx dx     7991 Oct 25  2016 QtIcon.png
drwxrwxr-x  5 dx dx     4096 Jul 19 04:03 Tools/
-rw-rw-r--  1 dx dx     8457 May 15 07:28 update.rcc
```

When I started qt-creator whether using `./qtcreator` binary or `./qtcreator.sh` script from `~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin` directory, it kept complaining about some creating file errors like:

> Cannot create file /home/dx/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/devices.xml: Permission denied

The `QtProject` directory:

```bsh
~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator$ ll
total 8104
drwxrwxr-x 6 dx dx    4096 Jul 19 04:37 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 dx dx    4096 Jul 19 04:37 ../
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 cmaketools.xml.gOCjwJ
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:36 cmaketools.xml.PwCOuf
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 cmaketools.xml.XxOPmc
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 debuggers.xml.boFrxT
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 debuggers.xml.rBVUir
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:36 debuggers.xml.VdsQsr
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:31 devices.xml.auccoN
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 devices.xml.UsjcFj
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 devices.xml.vATmgJ
drwxrwxr-x 3 dx dx    4096 Jul 19 04:37 generic-highlighter/
-rw-r--r-- 1 dx dx 8273920 Jul 19 04:37 helpcollection.qhc
drwxrwxr-x 2 dx dx    4096 Jul 19 04:31 macros/
drwxrwxr-x 2 dx dx    4096 Jul 19 04:31 mimetypes/
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 profiles.xml.cyDvrK
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 profiles.xml.THIUQP
drwxrwxr-x 2 dx dx    4096 Jul 19 04:37 qnx/
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:31 qtversion.xml.nsootr
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 qtversion.xml.WnHHHB
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 toolchains.xml.nSNCwd
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:37 toolchains.xml.PtcXlQ
---------- 1 dx dx       0 Jul 19 04:36 toolchains.xml.xKfoCl
```

It looks like the failing startup leaves a lot of temp files here, but the expected xml files are not created. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have an incomplete installation of Qt Creator, but you can also install Qt Creator (*qtcreator*) from the default Ubuntu repositories instead of manually downloading Qt Creator and installing it. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install qtcreator cmake g++ git qt5-default
```

After you have installed qt5-default you can run the following command to list other available Qt5 packages:

```
apt search qt5-*
```

Comment: The version in Ubuntu repo is kind of outdated, that why I chose to manually download qt5 and latest qt-creator. But I'll give it a try and see whether it works

Comment: I edited my answer to include Qt5.

Comment: It indeed works by installing from the official repo. But only with a version 3.5.1 for qt creator, which even lacks a proper file explorer inside IDE. Sigh...

Comment: In order to get up-to-date versions of IDEs it's worthwhile to update to at least the latest LTS release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 18.04 has Qt Creator version 4.5.2 and Ubuntu 19.04 has Qt Creator version 4.8.1.